# How can I open a docx file, find a particular string occurring at multiple places and add two lines after that in the whole document using python?

Tags: python

As I am new to the python programming, I want to open a .docx file, parse it, find occurrence of particular string in multiple places and then adding two lines after that in whole document. How can i do these thing using python script?

Comment: Did you try googling that first?

Comment: Yes... i googled it and all I manage to find is the method to do above things with .txt files using python. For .docx file, I  wrote a code that can open a docx file but i couldnt find how to append two lines at specific places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this as follows using `win32com`:

```
import win32com.client

search_for = "This is some text in my file"
add_lines = "^pLine1^pLine2^pLine3"     # ^p creates a new line

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = False
word.DisplayAlerts = False
doc = word.Documents.Open(r'c:\my_folder\my_file.docx')
const = win32com.client.constants

find = doc.Content.Find 
find.ClearFormatting()
find.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
find.Execute(Forward=True, Replace=const.wdReplaceAll, FindText=search_for, ReplaceWith=search_for+add_lines)

word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(r'c:\my_folder\my_file_output.docx')
word.Quit()
```

To change the colour of the replacement text you could also add the following before the `find.Execute`:

```
find.Replacement.Font.Color = 255       # wdColorRed
```

A full list of standard Word colours is listed on the [Microsoft site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196272.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Martin for the help!!! But I am getting an error message while running the script. Below is the  error:  File "C:\Users\welcome pc\Desktop\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    doc = word.Documents.Open(r'c:\my_folder\my_file.docx')
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 8, in Open
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Word', u'This file could not be found.\r (c:\\my_folder\\my_file.docx)', u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\1033\\WDMAIN11.CHM', 24654, -2146823114), None) Can you suggest where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you changed the script to point to your own file? You need to give it the full path also.

Comment: yes...i have done that and also i have given full path.Its a sample file, i created to check the code.

Comment: Your error message says `This file could not be found. (c:\\my_folder\\my_file.docx)`

Comment: You're welcome. If you are happy with the answer, you can click the grey tick to accept the solution.

Comment: whatif i want to change the color of any word in replacement. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Just add something like `find.Replacement.Font.Color = 255`

Comment: I tried that. it will change the color of whole replacement text. But i want to change color for only two lines i just added

Comment: You might need to do it in to multiple steps, ie first find/replace the text. Then re-find the new text and replace with the colour.